# Axios Proxy when using POST is not working

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

I'm having a problem on some of my request from my react application, all GET requests goes through my Cloud function without any issue however POST requests does not go through and send the traffic to localhost port 3000 instead, I have set up my Proxy in the Package.json and its working on GET requests so I can atleast assume that it should work.

Package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "socialapp-client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.8.35",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.0.0-beta.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": <Google Function link here>
}
```

The error I encountered when sending post request:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/user/image 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

When I'm using postman with the same payload and auth, it works, so I'm really baffled on what might be causing the issue.

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score -2):

I was having the same problem but in some moment I notice a unspect solution. The particular fetch problem was happening when my components received params by URL (useParams). I don't how but after avoid using this, I'd never had the same problem again.